# Apache RewriteRule RegEx not working as intended

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pcre, apache2.2

I want to rewrite the URLs:

```
/Files/ANYFILENAMEHERE?token=ANYTOKENHERE
```

to

```
/do_download.php?file=ANYFILENAMEHERE&token=ANYTOKENHERE
```

For this I am using the following rule in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Files\/([^\?]+)\?token=([a-z0-9]+)$ do_download.php?file=$1&token=$2 [L]
```

However, the URL does not get rewritten. It just returns a `404` error.
On <kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/)</kbd> in `PCRE` mode however it matches for some reason.

Why is this and how can I fix this? Am I doing a stupid mistake somewhere?

My Apache version is `2.2.31 (Unix)` btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match for the query string in a rewrite rule.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=([^&]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^Files/(.+) /do_download.php?file=$1&token=%1
```

Here the rewrite condition looks for the token in the query string while the rewrite rule handles the filename.

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=fa3b4b46-b0c9-5406-a25b-605ca687d8bd